# Get implemented interfaces of a type using Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, interface, mono, mono.cecil

Sorry if the question sounds trivial, I've read many discussions about that problem, but I'm not 100 percent sure if I got it correctly:

I want to get all interfaces, which are implemented by a class- then I can use following code:

```
foreach (TypeDefinition typeItem in currentAssembly.MainModule.Types)
{
  // if the class has interfaces, get them
  Mono.Collections.Generic.Collection<TypeReference> interfaceList = typeItem.Interfaces;
}
```

So the variable "interfaceList" should now contain all interfaces, which "typeItem" implements- it does not matter if the interfaces are implemented explicitly or implicitly?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Did you try your code?

Comment: Yes, I tried a more specific one. I'm able to create a list with interfaces but I cannot prove it for my current project- so I wanted to verify whether "typeItem.Interfaces" really provides a list of implemented interfaces or if there exists another relation

Comment: You can easy create testing cases, if you need some help I can write them down

Answer (score 1):

To find out if above code is working you need to create simple assemblies with following test cases. Then code some unit test and you are done.

Test cases:

1. Class without interface - array should be empty
2. Class with one interface - array should have one element
3. Class with multiple interfaces
4. Class which inherits class from point 1
5. Class which inherits class from point 3
6. Class which inherits class from point 2 and implements one more interface

If points 5 and 6 doesn't show correct number of interfaces you can sum up "this" class interfaces and "all-parents" class interfaces

Comment: Thank you for providing text cases!